# Eliminar parte del href

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, href

Hola mi duda es que tengo mis href de esta manera
`<a class="nav-link" href="?peticion=que-es">Qué es</a>`
y en mi URL se ve de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero que no aparezca el ?peticion=
para que mi URL quede nada mas como /que-es

quiero utilizar el .htaccess para realizar esta accion de que no aparezca

Answer (score 2):

Con este htaccess tu URL quedaría así; `index.php/?Que-es`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)peticion=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/?Que-es [L,R]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L,NE]
```

Si lo que busca es enviar parámetros por url, puede usar los métodos $_POST & $_GET para enviar y cachar datos en la URL, y en los endpoints puede definir un ruta y solo cambiar el valor del parametro;

```
www.mysite.com/posts?per_page=15&_embed&orderby=title&order=asc
```

por:

```
tusitio.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1   // Post con el ID 1  
tusitio.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories  // Todas las Categorias de los posts
```

[Breve ejemplo de REST API](https://codigoconjuan.com/que-es-la-wp-rest-api/)